# Sqrt Function asking for second parameter which in R Code

Tags: r

I am new to R code and trying different functions in R. However when I tried to use the sqrt function, it always give me a error: argument "which" is missing. When I tried to see what sqrt really is, this was showing in my console. y = if(which==1){sqrt(x)} else {log(x)}. Does anyone have idea why my sqrt function is different than the other's?

Comment: just do `rm('sqrt')` and now try running `sqrt(10)`

Comment: You likely created your own function with the same name which is blocking the default function. You can either remove your function of the same name as already suggested, or call the base function directly with `base::sqrt(2)`. In the future, avoid naming function that will conflict with default functions.